# MySQL/MariaDB read preference from slave with max staleness

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, database-replication, eventual-consistency

I am using Mysql/MariaDB with Innodb storage engine version 10.x.

I want to setup a cluster with master-slave configuration. There is an option to read data from slave using --innodb-read-only or --read-only.

**However in addition to the above, client needs to read the data from slave if and only if max slave lag is less than x seconds**.

Slaves can lag behind the primary due to network congestion, low disk throughput, long-running operations, etc. The read preference with max allowed staleness option should let application specify a maximum replication lag, or “staleness”, for reads from slaves. When a secondary’s estimated staleness exceeds, the client stops using it for read operations from slaves and start reading from master.

I would like to know if there is an option in MySql/InnoDB?

Answer (score 1):

There's no automatic option for switching the query to the master. This is handled by application logic.

You can run a query `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` and one of the fields returned is `Seconds_Behind_Master`. You would have to write application code to check this, and if the lag is greater than your threshold, query the master instead.

You might find some type of proxy that can do this logic for you. See https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2018/02/19/proxysql-series-mysql-replication-read-write-split-up/

It's not always the best option to treat a replica with X seconds of lag as unusable. Some queries are perfectly okay regardless of the lag. I wrote a presentation about this some years ago, and it includes some example queries.  [Read / Write Splitting with MySQL and PHP](https://www.percona.com/resources/technical-presentations/readwrite-splitting-mysql-and-php-percona-mysql-webinars) (Percona webinar 2013)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Actually my database cluster doesn't need to be strongly consistent and can afford few minutes delay. I would try ProxySQL anyways. Would be great if you can share some information about real-time use cases. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you take a look at the presentation I linked to? It's in there.

Comment: Yes Bill. Also saw ProxySQL is fault tolerant or highly available after v1.4.9 release. It looks promising...........I have to setup my DB cluster across regions and see how I would deploy ProxySQL cluster along with that. So asked about any reference to that. Never mind. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant use cases for read/write splitting in general. I can't help you with specific use of ProxySQL, I have not used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

- There are many Proxy products that may have code for such.
- If you automatically switch to the Master, then *it* may get overwhelmed, thereby leading to *worse* system problem.
- If you try to switch to another Slave, it is too easy to get into a flapping situation.
- Galera has a way to deal with "critical read", if you wanted to go to a Cluster setup instead of Master + Slaves.
- If part of the problem is the distance between Master and Slave, and if you switch to the Master, where is the Client?  If it is near the Slave, won't the added time to reach the master cancel out some of the benefit?
- Avoid long-running queries, beef up the Slave to avoid slow disks, speed up queries that are hitting the disk a lot, look into network improvements.

In summary, I don't like the idea of attempt to move a query to the Master; I would work on dealing with the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

[MariaDB MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/maxscale/) has multiple ways of dealing with replication lag.

The simplest method is to limit the maximum allowed replication lag with the [`max_slave_replication_lag`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-24-readwritesplit/#max_slave_replication_lag) parameter. This works exactly the way you described: if a slave is too many seconds behind the master, other slaves and, as a last resort, the master is used. This is the most common method of dealing with replication lag in MaxScale.

Another option is to use the [`causal_reads`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-24-readwritesplit/#causal_reads) feature which leverages the [`MASTER_GTID_WAIT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/master_gtid_wait/) and other features found in MariaDB 10.2 and newer versions. This allows read consistency without adding additional load on the master. This does come at the cost of latency: if the server is lagging several seconds behind the read could take longer. This option is used when data consistency is critical but the request latency is not as important.

The third option is to use the [CCRFilter](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-24-consistent-critical-read-filter/) to force reads to the master after a write happens. This is a simpler approach compared to `causal_reads` but it provides data consistency at the cost of increased load on the master.